sqlalchemy mapped_column wasn't found
I have the sqlalchemy version 2.0.29
SQLAlchemy                  2.0.29

but those code doesn't work, although I copy it from official documentation
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapped_column
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

Base = declarative_base()
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user_account"

    id = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = mapped_column(String(30), nullable=False)
    fullname = mapped_column(String)
    addresses = relationship("Address", back_populates="user")

I tried to reinstall sqlalchemy but it doesn't work
I also have installed my dependencies by using poetry
I had seen the answer on github to the similar question:
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey, Integer, String, Text
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapped_column, registry, relationshipar

but it didn't work to me
Finally solution:

I checked the python version and it was 3.9. sqlalchemy 2.0.29 didn't
compatible with that version, so guys if you're trying to figure out
the same issue just check out if python version the same as version in
ur base intepreter


how did you check the version?

@python_user by "pip list" and "poetry show" in poetry shell

so have you confirmed if you are executing the program using the same interpreter / venv?

@python_user i used  "poetry config virtualenvs.in-project true"

@python_user and "poetry env use "

I mean how are you running the code? python something.py? if so, can you do python -m pip list

@python_user im using fast api so i run the code using fast api commands

@python_user now im running the command "python -m pip list" and the outuput:  "SQLAlchemy                  2.0.29"

one last shot, what is the "fastapi command" you mention, IIRC fastapi has no CLI

@python_user now i didn't even run the code last time, but i use uvicorn main:app --reload

where is this uvicorn installed? in your venv? does uvicorn show up in your pip list?

yes, it showed. 0.22.0 version. I didn't have the problems with running the code. it runs ok. but i have problems with my models, cuz there isn't mapped_column

@python_user uvicorn installed in pyproject.toml

@python_user it occurred that nevertheless the python --version command printed the version 3.12.3 all that time i had been using pyhton 3.7.9. Ur answers brought me to that conclusion so thank u! U helped me so much

glad to have helped, upvoted, how did you find out the version change here?

@python_user I checked what interpreter was using pycharm and change settings in it. then i use the cmd to change the base interpreter for projects and set the venv to my project by ".\Scripts\activate", I wrote the solution

I checked the python version and it was 3.9. sqlalchemy 2.0.29 didn't compatible with that version, so guys if you're trying to figure out the same issue just check out if python version the same as version in ur base intepreter
